# How to containerize the spring boot application without installing docker and deploying in centos

Tags: spring-boot, docker, microservices, devops

I have a spring boot application in my local machine , i want to containerize it without installing docker in local machine and i want to deploy it in a Cent Os machine which docker has installed in an offline mode .

while i have tried to containerizing it by building an image file , it is actually looking for Docker Daemon in local and the build is getting failed.

Comment: In much the same way that you need `javac` to compile a Java application, you need the Docker daemon running to build a Docker image.  There’s not really any shortcut around that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Docker engine you cannot containerize the application, Docker daemon is needed for creating the container for your spring boot application in unix. You can use ECS on AWS that can create the container without docker but lot of configurations and deep knowledge is needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using GoogleContainerTools' Jib you can easily build a Docker compliant container image without Docker installed.

You need to install the Jib plugin in your pom.xml or gradle.build file.

Here is a simple example: https://www.baeldung.com/jib-dockerizing